When converting from a provisional directly to an international patent (PCT), are new claims and new matter allowed to be added to a PCT?
I've seen that new claims can be added to the non-provisional from the provisional US patent. The new claims get a new priority date of the non-pro submission.
If a non-pro does not require claims for its submission, is it true that the International submission is similar in that new claims may be added but the new claims would have the new priority date.
Essentially, can new claims, with supporting new matter be added to the PCT patent?

To the last question - yes include anything that would make it a better application. You don’t need to think of it as “adding”. In fact a professional would start from scratch to craft the best application possible to protect what you want protected with little regard for the provisional’s wording.
However, you might consider one or more independent claims that are well supported by the provisional even they do not represent the best-case claim, so you have them as a fallback. Note that are are a few times the claims in the PCT application can be amended along the way.
Claim priority to the first filed application on the subject matter and hope the provisional helps if intervening art is cited against you.
